# PayPalScriptProvider "Things don't appear to be working at the moment" when locale is zh-CN

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating PayPalScriptProvider in a multi-language web app and I am setting the locale based on the language user has selected on the web app.

[image]

When the locale set is en_HK and zh_HK, the button work correctly, opening the HTML form inline within the web app.

However when the [local is set to zh_CN](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#link-locale), a pop up appears saying "We're sorry, things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."

How do I resolve this error?

[image]

```
// React App
<PayPalScriptProvider key='paypal-script' options={{
  'locale': 'en_HK',
  'client-id': 'xxxxxx',
  'currency': 'HKD'
}}>
        
// handleLanguageChange()    
// paypal locale change
// const [{ options }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();
dispatch({
  type: "resetOptions",
  value: {
    ...options,
    locale: paypalLocale.get(locale),
    currency: 'HKD',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could tell only USD works with zh_CN, HKD and [other currencies](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/reference/currency-codes/) do not.

You can test this in the [vanilla JS SDK demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), it's not a PayPalScriptProvider issue.